# How to update subdoc data in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, get, mongoose, put

I am trying to update user.task.fixitItem, where the Task schema is embedded within the User schema.

Using this get,

```
app.get('/api/tasks/:id/edit', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  console.log('*** testing route GET /api/tasks/:id/edit', req.params);

  User.findOne({'task._id': req.params.id})
    .select('task.$')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if(!user) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
      }
      if(!err) {
        return res.render('tasks/edit', {task: user.task[0] });
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        console.log('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
        return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
      }
    }
  );

});
```

How do you write the put to update the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the update method with $set

```
User.update(
  { 'task._id': req.params.id }, 
  { $set: { 'task.$.fixitItem': 'new value' }},
  function(err, user) {

  }
 );
```

Comment: Aha, I believe my get is only passing the subdoc & does not pass along the parent user._id. I need to figure out how to pass that along as well and then I can update User as you recommend.

Comment: I set up my put like this

Comment: `app.put('/api/tasks/:id', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {

  User.update({ 'task._id': req.params.id }, { $set: { 'task.$.fixitItem': 'new value' }}
    .exec(function(err, user) {

          console.log("Updated Existing Task with ID: " + req.params.id);
          return res.render('/dashboard');

    })
  );
});` and I am now getting this error `"message": "Object # has no method 'exec'",
  "error": {}`

Comment: You actually need to remove the exec(), I've modified my answer